# Jquery val() cannot read html tags received by php echo

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, drupal

this is my code, i have send value to input :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Drupal.behaviors.devenirClientDepuisServiceform = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {



        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            //$('.webform-component--nom-abnonnement>input').val('<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>');
            //$('.webform-component--produits-choisie>input').val('<?php echo $produitnid ?>');

            jQuery('.webform-component--nom-abnonnement>input').val('<?php echo $produitname ?>');
            jQuery('.webform-component--produits-choisie>input').val('<?php echo $produitnid ?>');
            jQuery('.webform-component--type-de-client>input').val('<?php echo $type ?>');
            jQuery('.webform-component--contrat>input').val('<?php echo $imageUrl; ?>');

        });

    }
};  
//
</script>
```

$imageUrl is a text html
but jquery cannot understand and give me this error :

> SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

[image]

Comment: replace last echo with `<?php echo str_replace(["\r", "\n"], "", $imageUrl); ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with using these quotes  ` and  removing line break of last one

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        //$('.webform-component--nom-abnonnement>input').val('<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>');
        //$('.webform-component--produits-choisie>input').val('<?php echo $produitnid ?>');

        jQuery('.webform-component--nom-abnonnement>input').val(`<?php echo $produitname ; ?>`);
        jQuery('.webform-component--produits-choisie>input').val(`<?php echo $produitnid ; ?>`);
        jQuery('.webform-component--type-de-client>input').val(`<?php echo $type ?>`);
        jQuery('.webform-component--contrat>input').val(`<?php echo  str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $imageUrl); ?>`);

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to write ";".. add ; after every echo statement

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            //$('.webform-component--nom-abnonnement>input').val('<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>');
            //$('.webform-component--produits-choisie>input').val('<?php echo $produitnid; ?>');

            jQuery('.webform-component--nom-abnonnement>input').val('<?php echo $produitname; ?>');
            jQuery('.webform-component--produits-choisie>input').val('<?php echo $produitnid; ?>');
            jQuery('.webform-component--type-de-client>input').val('<?php echo $type; ?>');
            jQuery('.webform-component--contrat>input').val('<?php echo $imageUrl; ?>');

        });
```

Comment: Dhara Parmar: The last line of PHP statements doesn't need to end with semi colon.

Comment: what? what are you talking about?

Comment: `<?php echo $var; ?>` can be written `<?php echo $var ?>` ([PHP documentation: Instruction separation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php))

Comment: this is not applicable over here  bcz we are opening and closing braces every line.

Comment: @DharaParmar That's why it can be written without semicolons: http://imgur.com/UvujAX6